# Adding search usernames feature to SnapChat like application

Tags: objective-c, search

I currently have made a SnapChat like application using a TreeHouse tutorial.

The way the application was built, when you go to friends, then click edit on the top right, it shows you everyone that is registered. I don't want this, rather someone have to search for usernames.

I've added a search bar to the edit friends view controller and connected it to the .m file.

I was using help from this post but the search bar would not show any users when pressed: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/search-friends-ribbit-almost-complete

This is my current code for the EditFriendsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EditFriendsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user;

- (BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user;

@end
```

This is my current code for the EditFriendsViewController.m

```
#import "EditFriendsViewController.h"
#import "MSCellAccessory.h"


@interface EditFriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditFriendsViewController

UIColor *disclosureColor;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
       //set your user property to the first (and only) object in the objects array
self.user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
}];

self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

disclosureColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.553 green:0.439 blue:0.718 alpha:1.0];

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

//dismiss keyboard 
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

//Enable the cancel button when the user touches the search field
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = TRUE;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

//dsiable the cancel button when the user ends editing
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = FALSE;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

//dismiss keyboard
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];


//Strip the whitespace off the end of the search text
NSString *searchText = [self.searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


//Check to make sure the field isnt empty and Query parse for username in the text     field
if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:searchText];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            //check to make sure the query actually found a user
            if (objects.count > 0) {

                //found a user
               //set the user as the table views data source and reload the table view


            //A user was not found, display error message
            } else {

                //no user found

            }

            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } else {

          //error occurred
        }
    }];

}


}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.allUsers count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = self.user.username;

if ([self isFriend:user]) {
    cell.accessoryView = [MSCellAccessory accessoryWithType:FLAT_CHECKMARK     color:disclosureColor];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
}

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

if ([self isFriend:user]) {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;

    for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            [self.friends removeObject:friend];
            break;
        }
    }

    [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryView = [MSCellAccessory accessoryWithType:FLAT_CHECKMARK
color:disclosureColor];
    [self.friends addObject:user];
    [friendsRelation addObject:user];
}

[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

- (BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user {
for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
    if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
        return YES;
    }
}

return NO;
}


@end
```

Comment: Lots of code there. How far does it get? How much have you debugged?

Comment: @Wain Everyone runs with no issues, if I go to use the search bar and type in a test account username it doesn't show up. I'm not sure if I have debugged anything.

Comment: You haven't implemented the block to save the search result, and you apparently don't know if the search delegate methods are called?

Comment: @Wain Is that what I'm missing? Do you know what code I should add? Some what new to iOS coding not going to lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `//found a user`, replace with:

```
self.allUsers = objects;
```

This should get the results onto display.